Hover over an item, change the color of another
I have these 2 divs and I want to make it so if you hover over "square", "square2"'s color changes. How do i do this? Preferably in css, but js is also possible.
hover over square 1 --> square 2 is now red instead of green


square:hover {
  #square2.background_color: #ff0000;
}
<div class="square">
  <p class="square1_text">~66.6%</p>
</div>

<div class="square2">
  <p class="square2_text">~33.3%</p>
</div>




Change css on hover of sibling element

You can use the next-sibling combinator (+).


.square:hover + .square2 {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
<div class="square">
  <p class="square1_text">~66.6%</p>
</div>
<div class="square2">
  <p class="square2_text">~33.3%</p>
</div>
<button class="button"></button>




In CSS, there is no combinator for selecting a previous sibling. So, you can use JavaScript if you want both divs to highlight the other on hover:


const sq = document.querySelector('.square');
const sq2 = document.querySelector('.square2');
const squares = [sq, sq2];

squares.forEach(function(square, i) {
  square.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    squares[Math.abs(i - 1)].style.backgroundColor = '#ff0000';
  });
  square.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    squares[Math.abs(i - 1)].style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
  });
});
<body>
  <div class="square">
    <p class="square1_text">~66.6%</p>
  </div>
  <div class="square2">
    <p class="square2_text">~33.3%</p>
  </div>
  <button class="button"></button>
</body>






.square:hover + .square2 {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
<div class="square">
  <p class="square1_text">~66.6%</p>
</div>
<div class="square2">
  <p class="square2_text">~33.3%</p>
</div>
<button class="button"></button>




Please consider leaving a coment on why your solution will help the OP

Please see [answer]. You should provide some explanation for your solution.
